# CLION: WSL not found, ssh connected?

Tags: clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Today I got this error message: 
"WSL not found at: C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\debian.exe"

[image: Error message]

Before this message today, everything worked fine (I start Debian through start menu, restart the ssh service, then start CLion and it linked up just fine.).

The executable is there, just 0kb. The strange thing is that the Linux environment can be opened from windows as always (debian), I can ssh into it just fine (looks like CLion can as well, see picture).

[image: Toolchain window]
[image: Apps folder refered to]

This happened after an update tot CLion 2018.2.2 from 2018.2.1. Rolling back did not fix the issue.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Hello @Biswapriyo, I'm not entirely certain what you mean. Google was not really clear either, I understand that in the wsl dev cycle it was renamed from wsl.exe/bash.exe to _distribution_.exe? Do you suggest to rename debian.exe to wsl.exe/bash.exe?

Comment: Debian.exe or Ubuntu.exe opens wsl.exe. So I guess what happens if you use wsl.exe path instead of that path.

Comment: CLion (v. 2018.2.2) does not give me the option to select anything other than the pre-found debian.exe and ubuntu.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a fix for the issue. In Windows config select the apps list, find Debian and press advanced settings. Then end the service and recover it (the mild recovery was enough for my case). Although I'm not certain it aided in fixing the issue I've also removed the Jetbrains folder in the LocalCache/Local folder of the Debian folder in my AppData\Local\Packages.

Comment: Hi, I have met the same problem, could you please describe how to open "Windows config"? Is it `msconfig` command? But I cannot find "Debian" in the opened dialog.

Comment: Press start button (lower left corner) -> press configuration button (gear button) -> press apps -> find Debian in the list -> (I dont currently have Debian installed an my windows is in non-english so the following is a guess) Select debian, through right mouse button or another button there and then you should be in the menu that allows you to recover Debian. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description, I finally found it, however I tried recovering, resetting, even reinstalling, all have no luck. I thought it must be JetBrains's problem.

Comment: That's rough to hear, I'd advice you to file a bug report with JetBrains then. I hope you find a fix soon.