# CLion 2019.2.1 toolchain: WSL not found

Tags: clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu through the Windows store and then followed the Jetbrains CLion/WSL setup guide here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html

However after following that guide I was still an error in CLion saying "WSL not found"

[image: Toolchains page]
[image: WSL error message in Debug panel]

I tried restarting CLion but that didn't fix it.

I verified WSL works fine on my PC:

[image: using WSL in command prompt]

CLion version information:

```
CLion 2019.2.1
Build #CL-192.6262.62, built on August 21, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.39 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1987M
Cores: 8
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE
Non-Bundled Plugins:
```

Windows version: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1331]`

I found this related question but unfortunately repair/reset didn't work for me [CLION: WSL not found, ssh connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060650/clion-wsl-not-found-ssh-connected)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Seeing this currently with Windows 10 16299, CLion 2019.3.2, and WSL v1 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Maspe36 sadly nope :[ I ended up dual booting Ubuntu and doing my development there.. probably not too helpful unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunate, but thanks for tying up the loose end!

Comment: I had a coworker update my laptop and now my WSL doesn't work either

Comment: In his case, WSL works fine, its CLion that is not detecting it. I have Access to the whole JetBrains suite as I am a part time student, and I have played with Visual Studio CLion & V.S. Code. Personally, I find that CLion is the best IDE for developing a project. But honestly, for an environment, for the actual code writing process, V.S. Code has the best tooling hands down. And its portable, and WSL & V.S. Code are developed by the same company so they work seemlessly.

Comment: You should connect not localhost in CLion, but your actual WSL IP (`hostname -I`)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to delete deprecated option from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change ListenAddress to 0.0.0.0, learn your WSL IP (hostname -I) and change localhost to it in CLion toolchain config.

For this you need to:

1. Open WSL terminal
2. `su`
3. Enter windows user password
4. `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
5. Scroll to the bottom
6. Delete line 126 (those deprecated)
7. Change `ListenAddress 127.0.0.1` to `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0`
8. ctrl+o, cntrl+x
9. `service ssh restart`
10. `hostname -I`
11. Copy IP
12. In CLion > Settings > Buil & Debug > toolchains > WSL change localhost to copied IP

Note that this IP usually changes after reload. Use this tool to fight it https://github.com/shayne/go-wsl2-host