# Ubuntu WSL is listed in Clion toolchains but says "not found"

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, ubuntu-20.04, toolchain

Unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060650/clion-wsl-not-found-ssh-connected) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715802/clion-2019-2-1-toolchain-wsl-not-found), CLion seems to detect the WSL correctly:

[image: WSL Detected]

You can see that Ubuntu-20.04 is listed but still not found :

[image: Not found]

Versions :

- Windows 10 : 1803
- WSL : 1 (since windows 1803 does not support WSL 2)
- WSL Distrib : Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows store
- CLion : 2021.2.3

Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the CLion support and this if the answer (which fixed my problem)

> Actually, the best way to solve this is to update Windows. If it's not possible, then in CLion go to Help | Find Action, type "Registry...", select it and in the opened list find and and disable the wsl.execute.with.wsl.exe option. It should help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue seem to be, that `clion` can't find the `cmake`, C compiler, or C++ compiler of the WSL. My guess is that you haven't installed those yet.

You can install `gcc` with:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

[This article](https://medium.com/shehuawwal/using-wsl-toolchains-in-jetbrains-clion-on-windows-90c9fd07af17) explains how to build `cmake`:

> Go to — https://cmake.org/files/ That shows all the list of the versions of cmake, I use cmake-3.15.0-rc1.tar.gz.
>
> Open your terminal or bash and download it.
>
> ```
> wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.15/cmake-3.15.0-rc1.tar.gz
> ```
>
> After downloading, then untar.
>
> ```
> tar -xvzf cmake-3.15.0-rc1.tar.gz
> cd cmake-3.15.0-rc1/
> ./bootstrap
> sudo make
> sudo make install
> cd /bin/
> sudo cp cmake /usr/bin/
> ```
>
> Now don’t forget we are currently in cmake-3.15.0-rc1/ just go back by entering `cd ..`. that takes you up one directory back.
> Now copy the directory to /usr/bin/share
>
> ```
> sudo cp -r cmake-3.15.0-rc1/ /usr/share/cmake-3.15
> export CMAKE_ROOT=/usr/share/cmake-3.15
> ```

After you have done that, `clion` should be able to detect everything correctly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Actually, I already did what you proposed. It could work with a recent version of Windows. My problem is that my Windows verion is managed by my company so I can't control it. I asked to CLion support and I posted the solution as an answer

Comment: It works for me, but for CLion 2022.2 you need a more recent version of CMake (as you've said, go to [https://cmake.org/files/](https://cmake.org/files/), and then check the latest version)

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue today and this is what worked for me:

1. Upgrade your CLion IDE if possible.

   - On my CLion v2019.2.3, the IDE *wasn't* even able to detect that I had already installed 'wsl2 Ubuntu v22.04'. This was resolved by upgrading to CLion IDE v2023.1.3.
2. In your 'wsl2 Ubuntu shell terminal', update the package index files on your system.

   - `sudo apt update`
3. Install the *'build-essential'* package in your 'wsl2 Ubuntu shell terminal. These will contain the GNU/g++ compiler collection and a couple more libraries and tools needed for compiling a program.

   - `sudo apt install build-essential`
4. Install the *'cmake'* package in your 'wsl2 Ubuntu shell terminal.

   - `sudo apt install cmake`
5. Install the *'gdb'* debugger for C (and C++) in your 'wsl2 Ubuntu shell terminal.

   - `sudo apt install gdb`
6. Restart your IDE and reconfigure your *'Tool chain'* to use **WSL**. All entries will now be auto-detected.

[image]